# Karatsuba Multiplication Optimization in Ruby - Failing

Tags: ruby, algorithm, math

Multiplying 2 numbers of N digits where N is an even number. multiply(1234,5678) returns 7006652, which is the correct product. #multiply_opt should return the same value when passed the same arguments, but it does not.

Any ideas are always hugely appreciated!

```
def multiply(x, y)
  return x * y if x.to_s.length <= 1 && y.to_s.length <= 1

  n = x.to_s.length

  x_mid = x.to_s.length / 2
  y_mid = y.to_s.length / 2

  a = x.to_s[0..x_mid-1].to_i
  b = x.to_s[x_mid..-1].to_i
  c = y.to_s[0..y_mid-1].to_i
  d = y.to_s[y_mid..-1].to_i

  ac = multiply(a,c)
  ad = multiply(a,d)
  bc = multiply(b,c)
  bd = multiply(b,d)

  ((10**n) * ac) + (10**(n/2) * (ad + bc)) + bd
end

def multiply_opt(x, y)
  # Not sure if this base case is correct...
  return x * y if x.to_s.length <= 1 || y.to_s.length <= 1

  # Not sure exactly how to define n
  n = [x.to_s.length, y.to_s.length].max

  x_mid = x.to_s.length / 2
  y_mid = y.to_s.length / 2

  a = x.to_s[0..x_mid-1].to_i
  b = x.to_s[x_mid..-1].to_i
  c = y.to_s[0..y_mid-1].to_i
  d = y.to_s[y_mid..-1].to_i

  # Recursive Calls
  s1 = multiply_opt(a,c)
  s2 = multiply_opt(b,d)
  s3 = multiply_opt((a + b),(b + d))
  s4 = s3 - s1 - s2

  (10**n)*s1 + (10**(n/2)* s4) + s2
end
```

Comment: define "not working"

Comment: returns the wrong value

Comment: multply(1234,5678)  returns 7006652, which is the correct product. I am expecting #multiply_opt to return the same value when passed the same arguments.

Comment: Have you tried doing the operation by hand?  Can you get the right answer yourself?  If so, then have it do the operation and print out all of its intermediate work.

Comment: Your naming of variables for factor parts is, well, non intuitive to begin with, but where is `c` in `s3 = multiply_opt((a + b), (b + d))`?

Comment: Good catch greybeard!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you define separate `x_mid` and `y_mid` which is wrong. And that the split has to happen at the same places, i.e., at `n/2`, seen from the **lower** digits.

Where your example fails is at the 3rd multiplication, since the operands there have 2 and 3 digits. The split should separate the last digit. With your method, the 3 digit number is split as 1 and 2 digits, which is wrong.

---

**Further details:** Karatsuba starts with the idea to split your numbers as

```
x = x1*M+x0
y = y1*M+y0
```

so that the product

```
x*y = x1*y1*M^2+((x1+x0)*(y1+y0)-x1*y1-x0*y0)*M + x0*y0
```

can be computed using three multiplications of smaller numbers. Popular is using `M=B^k` with the number base `B`, so that `x0` and `y0` contain the lowest `k` digits of `x` and `y`.

In your example, you have to decide to either use `k=1` or `k=2` consistently, by the design of Karatsuba one would demand that `x,y<M^2`, which implies `k=2`.

---

With these ideas in mind, your algorithm should be modified to

```
def multiply_opt(x, y)
  # Not sure if this base case is correct...
  return x * y if x.to_s.length <= 1 || y.to_s.length <= 1

  # Not sure exactly how to define n
  n = [x.to_s.length, y.to_s.length].max
  k = (n+1) / 2

  x_mid = x.to_s.length - k
  y_mid = y.to_s.length - k

  a = x.to_s[0..x_mid-1].to_i
  b = x.to_s[x_mid..-1].to_i
  c = y.to_s[0..y_mid-1].to_i
  d = y.to_s[y_mid..-1].to_i

  # Recursive Calls
  s1 = multiply_opt(a,c)
  s2 = multiply_opt(b,d)
  s3 = multiply_opt((a + b),(c + d))
  s4 = s3 - s1 - s2

  (10**(2*k))*s1 + (10**k * s4) + s2
end
```

The splitting and reconstruction statements in the first method should be modified accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Why does the 3 digit number need to split as 2 and 1?

Comment: I believe the second line of the function should read n = [x.to_s.length, y.to_s.length].min rather than a call to max.

Comment: @jvanstry: No. In the combination (2,8) of lengths, this would generate a split of (7,1) in the second number. Notice that the above is only a proof-of-concept implementation. In a real implementation the numbers would be BigIntegers implemented as arrays of integer type. Then the split in the middle of the largest guarantees that the assembly in the last line has minimal overlap.